# How can I fix issues with Zend's CSRF tokens not validating?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, csrf, zend-view

I am having some trouble using Zend's CSRF tokens from Zend_Form...

Every time I submit a form I get a validation error ('identical' as CSRF uses)

Earlier in my project I had no issues whith this, but at that time I was simply using an `echo $this->form;` in my view where `form` is passed from the controller. I can make the issue go away if I go back to this 'echo ..$form', but I currently need to echo each element separately and one by one because I need much control over each element and how it's rendered. I also need the utmost security measures and especially the basics like CSRF.

This is how I am rendering my 'Login' page with form elements, the issue obviously starts here, but is identical anywhere I have a form (which is everywhere :) )

.

```
<form id="login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="<?php echo $form->getMethod() ?>" action="<?php echo $form->getAction() ?>">
<div class="login-section">
    <div class="form-container inputsLogin">
    <?php echo $form->agency->renderLabel() . $form->agency->renderViewHelper() ?>
    <br /><br />
    <?php  

    echo $form->username->renderLabel() . 
        $this->formText('username', '', array(
          'required' => True,
        )); 

    echo $form->password->renderLabel() . 
        $this->formPassword('password', '', array(
        'required' => True,
        ));

    echo $form->returnUrl->renderLabel() . $form->returnUrl->renderViewHelper();
    echo $form->csrf_token->renderLabel() . $form->csrf_token;

    ?>

    <div class="element">
          <?php echo $this->formSubmit('submit', 'Login') ?>
    </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </form>
```

I have extended Zend_Form to add the CSRF element, but early in the project I had it in each form class. I grab the CSRF element just as any other element in $form and echo it onto the view. I suspect that my CSRF is getting generated twice but expecting the first one, but I cannot tell. 
I have tried several things... echo the label, don't echo the label, completely generate the csrf element in my view, set timeout (or not).

Also, for clarity, here is how I declare my CSRF element in the form class...

```
class Application_Form_Actform extends Zend_Form {

    function __construct() 
    { 
        parent::__construct();

        $this->addElement('hash', 'csrf_token', array(
                    'required' => 'true',
                    'salt' => get_class($this) . 'unique',
                    'ignore' => true,
                    'timeout' => 60000,
                    'errorMessages' => array(
                        'Identical' => 'Form may have timed out, or there is an attempt at forgery (Security issue). Please submit form again.'
                        ), 

                    )); 
    }

}
```

UPDATE:
I think I am getting two tokens, here is the output of `var_dump($_SESSION);`:

```
array(2) { '__ZF' => array(1) { 'Zend_Form_Element_Hash_Application_Form_Loginunique_csrf_token' => array(2) { 'ENNH' => int(1) 'ENT' => int(1347378030) } } 

'Zend_Form_Element_Hash_Application_Form_Loginunique_csrf_token' => array(1) { 'hash' => string(32) "e3df9bf3a76cf53a804b337b8b513191" } }
```

And this is the token in the view source:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="a8727d61c656c64861181c7141d766a5" id="csrf_token" />
```

Comment: If you move the addElement for the hash before `parent::__construct()`, do you have more luck?  __construct calls `$form->init()` and doesn't execute any code after that so the CSRF may not be getting set up in the form correctly.

Comment: Just tried it, No difference. I can see in the source view that the element is being put into my form. I also get the same issue if I create the element within my view, extending Zend_Form is on my 'todo' along with fixing this issue so I can be sure to have CSRF on every form. I have a suspicion that SESSION gets one token, and (maybe) for some reason a second is being created and put into the form.

Comment: I also just tried 'console.log(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION); ?>);' and it seems to be empty. Could my session be empty, especially not containing my CSRF token?

Comment: you may want to check to see if you are getting expired due to hops. In the hash.php the initCsrfToken() is setting the expiration hops at 1. There is no accessor method in the class to change this, but you might want to change it manually for troubleshooting.